# Concatenate rows in Access based on two tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'd like to aggregate group membership based on location, date and group number into a single field with spaces as delimiters.

Table INDSIGHT:

```
    GROUP_IND | DATE_IND | STUDY_SITE | Subarea   
    01           9/9/2001   SDP          Shum
    01           9/9/2001   KOD          North 
    01           9/10/2001  SDP          Shum
    02           9/10/2001  SDP          Shum
    01           9/10/2001  KOD          East
```

Table IMAGES has:

```
GROUP_IMG | DATE    | STUDY_SITE | INDIVIDUAL
01          9/9/2001  SDP           003
01          9/9/2001  SDP           004
01          9/9/2001  KOD           A16
01          9/9/2001  KOD           019
01          9/9/2001  KOD           021
01          9/10/2001 SDP           003
02          9/10/2001 SDP           006
```

What I want is:

```
GROUP | DATE    | STUDY_SITE | Subarea | Individuals
01      9/9/2001  SDP           Shum      003   004
01      9/9/2001  KOD           North     A16   019   021
```

I have implemented the following code using Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function.

```sql
SELECT
    i.GROUP_IND,
    i.DATE_IND,
    i.STUDY_SITE,
    i.Subarea,
    ConcatRelated(
        "INDIVIDUAL",
        "IMAGES",
        "GROUP_IMG = '" & [GROUP_IND] & "'"
         and "DATE = '" & [DATE_IND] & "'"
         and "STUDY_SITE = '" & [STUDY_SITE]"'"
        ) AS Individuals
FROM INDSIGHT AS i;
```

That query runs without error, but its results are not correct. The results are listing every individual, not just individuals for specific groups.

Note the DATE fields are Date/Time and GROUP fields are text.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I see those errors now. I corrected them but am still getting the same error.

Comment: The query does not ask for a parameter. I've actually got it to work now with the above code and no errors, but the results are not correct.  The relationship between the two tables needs to be between not only group as written, but date and study site fields as well.

Comment: No longer getting the parameter error, but results are not correct. The results are listing every individual, not just individuals for specific groups.

Comment: DATE fields are Date/Time and GROUP fields are text.

Comment: Some of your comments have disappeared. The answer was the Group By query did work.

Comment: I removed that comment because I wasn't sure you need a `GROUP BY` after all.  But keep it handy in case you do need it.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample data, I think this query returns the results you requested.

```sql
SELECT
    i.GROUP_IND,
    i.DATE_IND,
    i.STUDY_SITE,
    i.Subarea,
    ConcatRelated(
        "INDIVIDUAL",
        "IMAGES",
        "GROUP_IMG = '" & i.GROUP_IND
            & "' AND [DATE] = " & Format(i.DATE_IND, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
            & " AND STUDY_SITE = '"
            & i.STUDY_SITE & "'",
        "INDIVIDUAL",
        " "
        ) AS Individuals
FROM INDSIGHT AS i;
```

Notes:

- the field named `[DATE]` is enclosed in square brackets because it is a reserved word
- literal date values are delimited with `#` characters
- the third argument to `ConcatRelated` must be a single string; if you need to adjust anything there, be careful with the quoting
- I added a string for the fourth argument, *strOrderBy*, because the db engine wouldn't let me leave it blank when supplying the fifth argument, *strSeparator*.  Change the ordering to taste. :-)

If your actual full data set contains multiple rows for the same combinations of *GROUP_IND*, *DATE_IND*, *STUDY_SITE*, and *Subarea*, you will probably want to make it a `GROUP BY` query instead.  Leave `ConcatRelated` out when you create the `GROUP BY`, and add it back only after you have the `GROUP BY` working correctly.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for being so patient with this (and me).

Comment: Note I updated this answer with a *strOrderBy* argument which made more sense to me.  The revised query runs without error against your sample data, but I'm not sure that is the order you want.